# Python List: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, string

When I try to print `splited_data[1]` I'm getting error message `IndexError: list index out of range`, On the other hand `splited_data[0]` is working fine.
I want to insert data into MySQL. `splited_data[0]` are my MySQL columns and `splited_data[1]` is mysql column values. I want if `splited_data[1]` is empty then insert empty string in mysql. But I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range`. How to avoid this error? Please help me. thank you

Here is my code. Which is working fine. I'm only get this error message when `splited_data[1]` is empty.

```
    def clean(data):
        data = data.replace('[[','')
        data = data.replace(']]','')
        data = data.replace(']','')
        data = data.replace('[','')
        data = data.replace('|','')
        data = data.replace("''",'')
        data = data.replace("<br/>",',')
        return data


for t in xml.findall('//{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.5/}text'):
    m = re.search(r'(?ms).*?{{(Infobox film.*?)}}', t.text)
    if m:
        k =  m.group(1)
        k.encode('utf-8')
        clean_data = clean(k) #Clean function is used to replace garbase data from text
        filter_data = clean_data.splitlines(True) # splited data with lines
        filter_data.pop(0)
        for index,item in enumerate(filter_data):
                splited_data = item.split(' = ',1)
                print splited_data[0],splited_data[1]

# splited_data[0] used as mysql column 
# splited_data[1] used as mysql values
```

here is Splited_data data

```
[u' music         ', u'Jatin Sharma\n']
[u' cinematography', u'\n']
[u' released      ', u'Film datedf=y201124']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
split_data = item.partition('=')
# If there was an '=', then it is now in split_data[1],
# and the pieces you want are split_data[0] and split_data[2].
# Otherwise, split_data[0] is the whole string, and
# split_data[1] and split_data[2] are empty strings ('').
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the whitespace on both sides of the equals sign, like this:

```
splited_data = item.split('=',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `list` is contiguous. So you need to make sure it's length is greater than your index before you try to access it.

```
'' if len(splited_data) < 2 else splited_data[1]
```

You could also check before you split:

```
if '=' in item:
    col, val=item.split('=',1)
else:
    col, val=item, ''
```